# How to map and reduce over an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I count the prices together from the following array of objects:

```
const cars = [
{
    price: 10000,
    car: 'audi'
},
{
    price: 10000,
    car: 'audi'
},
{
    price: 10000,
    car: 'nissan'
},
{
    price: 10000,
    car: 'nissan'
},
{
    price: 20000,
    car: 'mazda'
},
{
    price: 10000,
    car: 'nissan'
},
];
```

So that I would get an array of objects, with the total prices:

```
const cars = [
{
    price: 20000,
    car: 'audi'
},
{
    price: 30000,
    car: 'nissan'
},
{
    price: 20000,
    car: 'mazda'
}
];
```

Tried to map over the array, and then reduce, but how do i keep the structure, so that I get back an array of objects? This is incorrect:

```
 const newCarsArray = cars.map(item => {
     return(
        //cars.reduce ?
     )
 });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of this question.

Comment: So loop over and make a hash with the values and than convert that hash back into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce your array to an object keyed by car, holding the total, then it's pretty simple to convert that back to your format

```js
const cars = [{price: 10000, car: 'audi'},{price: 10000, car: 'audi'},{price: 10000, car: 'nissan'},{price: 10000, car: 'nissan'}, {price: 20000,        car: 'mazda'}, {price: 10000, car: 'nissan'}];

var map = cars.reduce((map, car) => {
  map[car.car] = map[car.car] ? map[car.car] + car.price : car.price;
  return map;
}, {});

console.log(map); // {audi: 20000, nissan: 30000, mazda: 20000}

var array = Object.keys(map).map( car => ({car: car, price: map[car]}));

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce, however a simple forEach in conjunction with a hashtable does it:

```
var companies = {}, result = [];

cars.forEach(function(el){
 if(companies[el.car]){
   companies[el.car].price += el.price;
 }else{
   result.push( companies[el.car] = Object.assign({},el));
 }
});
```

A reduce approach would look like this:

```
var result = cars.reduce((res,el)=> (
   ( 
     res.find(c => c.car === el.car ) 
     || res[res.push({price:0,car:el.car})-1] 
   ).price += el.price,res
),[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the two-stage `reduce` then `map` process.

First get an object with the car name as the unique keys, the price as the value:

```
var obj = cars.reduce((p, c) => {
  const key = c.car;

  // If the key doesn't exist create it
  // and set the value to zero
  p[key] = p[key] || 0;
  p[key] += c.price;
  return p;
}, {});
```

Then `map` over the keys of that object to produce a new array of objects:

```
var out = Object.keys(obj).map(p => {
  return { price: p, car: obj[p] };
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mupdLnhc/)**

Answer (score 0):

First create a `hashtable` with the unique objects and accumulated price and then use `#map()` to group them up - see demo below:

```js
const cars=[{price:10000,car:'audi'},{price:10000,car:'audi'},{price:10000,car:'nissan'},{price:10000,car:'nissan'},{price:20000,car:'mazda'},{price:10000,car:'nissan'},];

// create a hash first, and accumulate price
var hash = cars.reduce(function(p,c) {
  if(p[c.car]) {
    p[c.car].price += c.price;
  } else {
    p[c.car] = c;
  }
  return p;
}, Object.create(null));

// now convert to array
var result = Object.keys(hash).map(function(e){
  return hash[e];
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const cars = [
{
    price: 10000,
    car: 'audi'
},
{
    price: 10000,
    car: 'audi'
},
{
    price: 10000,
    car: 'nissan'
},
{
    price: 10000,
    car: 'nissan'
},
{
    price: 20000,
    car: 'mazda'
},
{
    price: 10000,
    car: 'nissan'
},
];

const result = Object.values(cars.reduce((prices, carInfo) => {
  if (prices.hasOwnProperty(carInfo.car)) {
    prices[carInfo.car].price += carInfo.price;
  } else {
    prices[carInfo.car] = Object.assign(carInfo);
  }
  return prices;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using a `Array.prototype.reduce()` method just as you said:

```
function groupAndSumCars(elements) {
    return elements.reduce(function (accumulator, element) {
        // Check if a group for that car already exists,
        // ".find()" returns undefined if nothing has been found
        const groupElement = accumulator.find(function (group) {
            return group.car === element.car;
        });

        // Group not created yet, create a new one
        if (!groupElement) {
            accumulator.push(element);

            return accumulator;
        }

        // Group already exists, increment "price" counter
        groupElement.price += element.price;

        return accumulator;
    }, []);
}
```

If you care about the performance, you should replace the `.find()` piece with something more performant (for example, you could use a temporary object to store group elements, or create a temporary [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)).