# javascript reduce over multiple keys of objects in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash, reduce

I have have map of Object of the following type (example data below)

```
{[date:string]:Array<{[type:string]:{amount:number, price:number}}>}
```

And I need to reduce the array to a single object of amount sum and price averaged

I have read a couple of post on how to reduce data over an object like

[How to map and reduce over an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45637465/how-to-map-and-reduce-over-an-array-of-objects)

[Javascript reduce on array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732043/javascript-reduce-on-array-of-objects)

In my case the "type" is a ENUM of ["PV","BHKW","FALLBACK"] but it could be extended. Apart from writing declarative for in loops, i can't figure out how to use array.reduce to accomplish this more elegantly.

Any suggestions?

```
{
    "2018-08-01T11:00:00+02:00": [
        {
            "BHKW": {
                "amount": 131,
                "price": 85
            },
            "FALLBACK": {
                "amount": 84,
                "price": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "BHKW": {
                "amount": 307,
                "price": 58
            },
            "PV": {
                "amount": 4,
                "price": 60
            }
        }
    ],
    "2018-08-01T12:00:00+02:00": [
        {
            "BHKW": {
                "amount": 288,
                "price": 59
            },
            "PV": {
                "amount": 742,
                "price": 73
            }
        },
        {
            "BHKW": {
                "amount": 250,
                "price": 49
            },
            "PV": {
                "amount": 507,
                "price": 98
            }
        },
        {
            "PV": {
                "amount": 368,
                "price": 22
            },
            "BHKW": {
                "amount": 357,
                "price": 73
            }
        },
        {
            "FALLBACK": {
                "amount": 135,
                "price": 62
            },
            "BHKW": {
                "amount": 129,
                "price": 93
            }
        }
    ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`lodash#mapValues`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#mapValues) to transform each value of the object `data` object. To combine all objects with the same key values, you can use [`lodash#mergeWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#mergeWith) with the callback testing if the keys being transformed will be evaluated.

```
const result = _.mapValues(data, collection => 
  _.mergeWith({}, ...collection, (a = 0, b = 0, key) =>
    ['amount', 'price'].includes(key)
      ? a + b
      : void 0 // is equivalent to undefined to retain current value
  ));
```

```js
const data = {
    "2018-08-01T11:00:00+02:00": [
        {
            "BHKW": {
                "amount": 131,
                "price": 85
            },
            "FALLBACK": {
                "amount": 84,
                "price": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "BHKW": {
                "amount": 307,
                "price": 58
            },
            "PV": {
                "amount": 4,
                "price": 60
            }
        }
    ],
    "2018-08-01T12:00:00+02:00": [
        {
            "BHKW": {
                "amount": 288,
                "price": 59
            },
            "PV": {
                "amount": 742,
                "price": 73
            }
        },
        {
            "BHKW": {
                "amount": 250,
                "price": 49
            },
            "PV": {
                "amount": 507,
                "price": 98
            }
        },
        {
            "PV": {
                "amount": 368,
                "price": 22
            },
            "BHKW": {
                "amount": 357,
                "price": 73
            }
        },
        {
            "FALLBACK": {
                "amount": 135,
                "price": 62
            },
            "BHKW": {
                "amount": 129,
                "price": 93
            }
        }
    ]
};

const result = _.mapValues(data, collection => 
  _.mergeWith({}, ...collection, (a = 0, b = 0, key) =>
    ['amount', 'price'].includes(key)
      ? a + b
      : void 0 // is equivalent to undefined to retain current value
  ));
  
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;top:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

solved it!

```
var x = _.reduce(
    list,
    (acc, item) => {
        for (const key in item) {
            if (!acc[key]) {
                acc[key] = { price: 0, amount: 0 };
            }

            if (item[key] && item[key].price) {
                acc[key].price += item[key].price;
            }

            if (item[key] && item[key].amount) {
                acc[key].amount += item[key].amount;
            }
        }
        return acc;
    },
    {}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way (although not as elegant as the `_.merge` approach already posted) is with `_.mapValues/_.reduce/_.assignWith or _.extendWith`:

```js
var data = { "2018-08-01T11:00:00+02:00": [{ "BHKW": { "amount": 131, "price": 85 }, "FALLBACK": { "amount": 84, "price": 1 } }, { "BHKW": { "amount": 307, "price": 58 }, "PV": { "amount": 4, "price": 60 } } ], "2018-08-01T12:00:00+02:00": [{ "BHKW": { "amount": 288, "price": 59 }, "PV": { "amount": 742, "price": 73 } }, { "BHKW": { "amount": 250, "price": 49 }, "PV": { "amount": 507, "price": 98 } }, { "PV": { "amount": 368, "price": 22 }, "BHKW": { "amount": 357, "price": 73 } }, { "FALLBACK": { "amount": 135, "price": 62 }, "BHKW": { "amount": 129, "price": 93 } } ] }

var result =
  _.mapValues(data, (x) =>
    _.reduce(x, (r, c) =>
      _.assignWith(r, c, (o, s) =>
        o && s ? ({ amount: o.amount + s.amount, price: o.price + s.price }) : {...o, ...s})
    )
  )

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```